# How to use check_password function in django

Tags: django

I'm a beginner in Django. I have a signup form with only 2 fields. Username and Password. The password is encrypted using the pbkdf2_sha256 algorithm.
I want to login using the username and password.so the password that I'm inputting in the login page must be checked with the encrypted password. How to do that?. Also, please explain what authenticate and check_password function does?

```
def save(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       name = request.POST.get('name')
       password = request.POST.get('pass')
       enc_pass = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(password,rounds=12000,salt_size = 32)
       a = signup(username = name, password = enc_pass)
       a.save()
   return render(request,'save.html')
def login(request):
   if request.method  == 'POST':

       username        = request.POST.get('user')
       password1          = request.POST.get('password1')
       p = check_password(password=password1)
      if signup.objects.filter(username__exact=username).exists() and p is True:
           return HttpResponse("Success")
     else:
           return HttpResponse("Invalid Credentials")
   return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: code I wrote is not finished.Just need to know how to use check_password function

Comment: Honestly, just try using the default `authenticate` method to lookup a user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`check_password`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password) does not work like this. To make it work, you need to use Django's own authentication system. If you are concerned about using `pbkdf2_sha256`, Django provides this [**`hasher`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#included-hashers). To use this with you own auth system, add it to settings:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
]
```

And in django authentication, you do not need to hash it manually, django will take care of it itself. All you need to do is save the user like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password, #.. other required fields)
```

And to check password:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
user.check_password(password)
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/)

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
if check_password(password_user_entered, request.user.password):
    # You can authenticate
```

Here, `password_user_entered` is password that came from the request(or, pw to be checked). And, `request.user.password` which is the password with which we want to compare.